# Java RestFb, can not get return value from an action listener

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I am trying to get access-token from the Facebook using restfb api everything works and i can print the access-token but when i try to return it i get an empty value..
Following is the code

```
public String showLogin() {
DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.LATEST);
ScopeBuilder scopes = new ScopeBuilder();
String loadUrl = facebookClient.getLoginDialogUrl(appId, SUCCESS_URL, scopes);
webEngine.load(loadUrl + "&display=popup&response_type=code");
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
  (ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
      return;
    }

    String myUrl = webEngine.getLocation();

    if ("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/close".equals(myUrl)) {
      System.out.println("dialog closed");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    String u="https://www.creativecorner7.com/";
    if (myUrl.startsWith(u)) {
      int pos = myUrl.indexOf("code=");
      code = myUrl.substring(pos + "code=".length());
      FacebookClient.AccessToken token = facebookClient.obtainUserAccessToken(appId,
              appSecret, SUCCESS_URL, code);
      acctoken=token.getAccessToken();
        System.out.println(acctoken);
    }

  });
 return acctoken;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Webengine works asynchronously, so the `acctoken` is returned *before* the `Webengine#load` method is finished. You have to think of another approach.

Answer (score 0):

By using getters and setters for the acctoken i was able to tackle the problem.